# Cannot read keyboard in a loop in Python

Tags: python, python-keyboard

I need a Python script to read arrow keys and react to them.

As a first test:

```
import keyboard
import time

while True:
 if keyboard.is_pressed("i"):
  print("up")
 if keyboard.is_pressed("k"):
  print("down")
 time.sleep(0.1)
```

It never prints "up" but, prints characters:

```
i
i
j
^[[A
^[[D
^[[C
```

I run the script in debian terminal:

```
sudo python3 test.py
```

I expect **up** or **down** to show up in the terminal.

What am I missing?

Comment: Check out the documenation.  https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#repeatedly-waiting-for-a-key-press.  They recommend against writing the loop the way you have.

Comment: When I run your script I get the error: **ValueError: ("Key 'i' is not mapped to any known key.", ValueError('Unrecognized character: i'))**

Comment: I certainly dont want to wait for the key, I need a non blocking loop

Comment: Then don't write it in a blocking loop.

Comment: One-space indentation. Really?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from pynput import keyboard

def on_key_press(key):
    try:
        # Print the key that was pressed
        print(f'Key {key} pressed')
    except AttributeError:
        # Some special keys may not have a name attribute
        print(f'Special key {key} pressed')
 
def on_key_release(key):
    try:
        # Print the key that was released
        print(f'Key {key} released')
    except AttributeError:
        # Some special keys may not have a name attribute
        print(f'Special key {key} released')
 
# Create a keyboard listener
listener = keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_key_press, on_release=on_key_release)

# Start listening for keyboard events

listener.start()

# Keep the listener running

listener.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use the `keyboard` library, but the library might not be capturing key events correctly. To detect arrow key presses, you can use the `curses` library instead.

Like this:

```
import curses

stdscr = curses.initscr()
curses.cbreak()
stdscr.keypad(1)

try:
    while True:
        key = stdscr.getch()
        if key == ord('i'):
            print("up")
        elif key == ord('k'):
            print("down")

finally:
    curses.endwin()
```

Also to run the script, you don't need to use `sudo`. Just execute `python3 test.py`.

Comment: it works but curses is used to create terminal ui's. still a decent workaround thou. cant believe that python cannot just read keyboard events natively

Comment: Yes you're right that curses is often used for creating terminal ui's. It's a common choice for capturing keyboard events in a terminal because it provides a way to handle input in a more interactive and platform-independent manner! Unfortunately, Python's SL does not offer a simple, cross-platform way to capture keyboard events natively for arbitrary keys!

Comment: also how do you detect when the key is released ?

Comment: To detect when a key is released in the curses library, enable non-blocking input with stdscr.nodelay(1). In the loop, use stdscr.getch() to check for key presses and releases. When a key is released, stdscr.getch() returns -1, allowing you to do whatever you want to do when key is released i.e. when a key is no longer held down. This will allow you to detect both key presses and releases.

Comment: Btw, your code is working absolutely fine on my machine!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import keyboard

def on_key_event(e):
    if e.event_type == keyboard.KEY_DOWN:
        if e.name == 'i':
            print('up')
        elif e.name == 'j':
            print('down')

keyboard.on_press(on_key_event)

keyboard.wait('esc')  # exit key

keyboard.unhook_all()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).